# Flutter where to put http.get

Tags: flutter

I am making lecture room reservation system.

```
class SearchView2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchViewState2 createState() => _SearchViewState2();
}

class _SearchViewState2 extends State<SearchView2> {
  String building = Get.arguments;
  List data = [];
  String roomID = "";
  int reserved = 0;
  int using = 0;
  Future<String> getData() async {
    http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "https://gcse.doky.space/api/schedule/classrooms?bd=$building"));
    http.Response res2 = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "https://gcse.doky.space/api/reservation/currtotal?bd=$building&crn=$roomID"));
    reserved = jsonDecode(res2.body)["reserved"];
    using = jsonDecode(res2.body)["using"];

    this.setState(() {
      data = jsonDecode(res.body)["result"];
    });

    return "success";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('강의실 선택')),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {          
          roomID = data[index];
          return new Card(
            child: ListTile(
                onTap: () async {}, title: Text(data[index] + " " + reserved)),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to get 'using' and 'reserved' data and print them in the list view.

But roomID is in Listview

I want data[index] as roomID but with my code roomID will be null, so it won't print the result.

Where should I move http.Response res2? (not res)

Or is there other way to get using and reserved data in the listview?

Comment: Hi There. What is the value of `building` ?

Comment: I used getx for building value and it is from previous view that I made. So building value is already initialized and it never be changed.

Comment: I understand, I was asking the value so that I could replicate your code, to see what data is coming so that I can provide you full code for showing a `ListView`.

Comment: https://github.com/GC211SE/backend/blob/master/api.md
result here

Comment: got it. posting answer in few minutes.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Check it out. You can copy paste the code from paste bin directly. Tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a single `building` and multiple `rooms` in that building. So, fetching a `building` data along with the data of all it's `rooms` together will take too much time.

Instead, you can break it into two parts.

For fetching `Building` data,

```
Future<List<String>> getData() async {
  http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://gcse.doky.space/api/schedule/classrooms?bd=$building"));
  return (jsonDecode(res.body)["result"] as List)
    .map<String>((e) => e.toString())
    .toList();
}
```

Then, for fetching each room data, Here you have to pass `roomID`.

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getRoomData(String roomID) async {
  http.Response res2 = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://gcse.doky.space/api/reservation/currtotal?bd=$building&crn=$roomID"));
  return {
    'reserved': jsonDecode(res2.body)["success"]["reserved"],
    'using': jsonDecode(res2.body)["success"]["using"],
  };
}
```

Now, you can use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget to build something that depends on fetching data asynchronously.

You also don't need a `StatefulWidget` since you are using `FutureBuilder` and can remove all unnecessary local variables you have defined.

Here is the full working code. [PasteBin Working Code](https://pastebin.com/tJrR2j6M).

Just replace your entire `SearchView2` code with the code in the link.

This is the output.

[image]

Comment: `
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\admin\Desktop\flutter\frontent\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: cmd: Failure calling service package: Broken pipe (32)
`
error occurs

Comment: Try uninstall the app from your device and re build from code.

Comment: I want to send room and building value to other view. 
like Get.to(() => ReservationView(), arguments: data[index]);
Should I just make list and put [building, roomID]?

Comment: Yes, that should work. try it out, tell me if there is any issue.

Comment: Inside `buildRoomCard` you have access to both `building` and `roomID`. From there you can do it.

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Please do consider upvoting the answer as well if the explanation is clear. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you using it ?

Comment: I used print function
return Card(
            child: ListTile(
          onTap: () {
            Get.to(() => ReservationView(), arguments: data);
            print(data);

(data is [building, roomID] list)
But it takes wrong roomID when I click listview.

Comment: can you create a pastebin and paste your code and share it here. https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Try like this, `ReservationView(roomID: roomID, building: building)` and inside your `ReservationView`, put `constructor` `ReservationView({ this.roomID, this.building })`

Comment: I just moved onTap under the title and it worked. Thanks anyway.